# How I am getting, How much data are displaying in my TableView after searching in SearchBar?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

I have a problem Please help me.

I am displaying some Textual data in TableView. and one SearchBar attached with Table-View. When I am searching any thing in SearchBar then TableView working properly fine. But I want to Row-Count.

I want to show one pop-up when no Data found.or Not any Data in Table view according to Search Bar text.

How I will do this thing. Please help me!!!
any suggestion will appreciated!!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there is impossible to get search row count with standart SDK API. But you can use this module https://github.com/farwayer/TiListSearchItems

Comment: I have check this, In this module using List View. now working my code :(
But I give you upvote